# Need to return object before/ignoring path in spark java

Tags: spark-java

I want to write my own very basic caching inside my sparkjava server.

My thought is to cache the response somewhere, and have some code in a `before` block that checks if the incoming path is one that should return the cached string/response or should carry on to the appropriate `path` and calculate the response (storing it in the cache for future calls).

My question is, if i understand sparkjava properly, is how can i return the response from inside the `before` block and not carry on into the `path`

Or maybe it's not possible?

Alternatively, i can check inside every `path` at the beginning of each, to either use the cached response or create a fresh one, but writing this in every `path` block instead of writing it once in a `before` feels wrong/is needlessly duplicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can return any string data in a `halt()` statement during your before-filter. This approach is outlined in the Spark documentation located at: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#halting.

Example:

```
before( (req, res) -> {

   // somehow prove the request matches a request that was previously cached
   if(req.contextPath() == known_cached_path){
      halt(304, cached_data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Ah very interesting, I'm on a student project right now but will definitely look into this and get back to you if it works. I'll also give you the approved answer

Comment: Hey finally gotten round to testing this and I think it's working perfectly!! Thanks so much for this, time to add caching to all my endpoints, and take some load off my tiny server